# Why does my final exported image appear more desaturated than my render?

Tags: rendering, light, color, color-management

Why does my final exported image seem more desaturated than my render? In Blender it seems full of color but once exported as a PNG it seems desaturated a bit...

*Sorry, I am completely new to the program and this is my first time using it.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can we know? Can we at least have a look at them, or perhaps your render setup, compositing nodes, etc?

Comment: This needs more infos and/or screenshots.*appear*, *seems* - Is it actually desatured? What viewer are you using? Is it not the same when you render it, save it, and load it into Blender?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sorry, this is my first time using the program and this site. I hope the images I added help clarify the issue, if at all.

Comment: @Leander Sorry, this is my first time using the program and this site. I hope the images I added help clarify the issue, if at all.

Comment: Have you tried saving with an HDR format, see if the problem persists?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos How exactly do I do that?

Comment: @JoelGodina The additional information is helpful and the image **is** definately less saturated. It is still hard to answer. Can you [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? And in what program did you open the png (Windows Photo Viewer, Irfanview, Chrome ...)? Maybe it is simply image viewer software acting strange? It could also be a transparency issue, have you tried [saving with alpha](https://imgur.com/a/q9WIU)?

Comment: @Leander Attempted to save the image with alpha and the issue persists. I also double checked the program in which I opened the file and it appears less saturated with every program. Thank you for your advice. I will continue to try and figure this out. Any further recommendations are really helpful!

Comment: It can be a lot of things, better to provide the blend file with http://pasteall.org/blend/ . But check if you have something like a background disable in viewport and not in render, or if you have the save buffers option enable in Render panel --> Performance

Comment: Sorry haven't read correctly, perhaps check the export as render option when saving, active or not.